# Select radio input based on which link clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a specific input checked when a link is clicked. There are numerous links a radio buttons and I somehow want to use variables instead of having a function for each link. Is this possible?

At the moment this is what I have

```js
function check117() {
    document.getElementById("option-i-117").checked = true;
 }
 function check118() {
    document.getElementById("option-i-118").checked = true;
}
function check119() {
    document.getElementById("option-i-119").checked = true;
}
function check120() {
    document.getElementById("option-i-120").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<a class="option-i-117" onclick="check117()">Option 117</a>
<a class="option-i-118" onclick="check118()">Option 118</a>
<a class="option-i-119" onclick="check119()">Option 119</a>
<a class="option-i-120" onclick="check120()">Option 120</a>
        
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
```

But I have over 50 inputs so ideally, I would like to use variables in the javascript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need multiple functions. Simply pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function to access the `class` which can be used in `getElementById()`:

```js
function check(el) {
  document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('class')).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<a class="option-i-117" onclick="check(this)">Option 117</a>
<a class="option-i-118" onclick="check(this)">Option 118</a>
<a class="option-i-119" onclick="check(this)">Option 119</a>
<a class="option-i-120" onclick="check(this)">Option 120</a>

<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
```

**OR:** Since you have large number (> 50) of elements on which you need to attach the event (`click`), instead of doing it manually, you can attach the function with the magic of [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[class^=option-i-]').forEach(function(anchor){
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function check() {
    document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('class')).checked = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="option-i-117">Option 117</a>
<a class="option-i-118">Option 118</a>
<a class="option-i-119">Option 119</a>
<a class="option-i-120">Option 120</a>

<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
```

Answer (score 1):

You no need javascript.

```css
label, input {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:20vw;
  text-align:right;}
div {
  margin: 2em;}
```

```html
<label for="option-i-117">Option 117</label>&nbsp;
<label for="option-i-118">Option 118</label>&nbsp;
<label for="option-i-119">Option 119</label>&nbsp;
<label for="option-i-120">Option 120</label>&nbsp;

<div>If you click on text up:</div>
<hr/>
<div>then here input change check status</div>

<label for="option-i-117">
  <input type="radio" name="option[235]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
  Option 117
</label>
<label for="option-i-118">
  <input type="radio" name="option[235]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
  Option 118
</label>
<label for="option-i-119">
  <input type="radio" name="option[235]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
  Option 119
</label>
<label for="option-i-120">
  <input type="radio" name="option[235]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
  Option 120
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send the serial number of the item to the function:

```
<a class="option-i-117" onclick="check(117)">Option 117</a>
<a class="option-i-118" onclick="check(118)">Option 118</a>
<a class="option-i-119" onclick="check(119)">Option 119</a>
<a class="option-i-120" onclick="check(120)">Option 120</a>

<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
<input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
```

than, in the function, add it to the id pattern:

```
function check(i){
      document.getElementById("option-i-"+i).checked = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listener for the clicks on the parent container of the links. This way you're only attaching a listener to a single DOM element e.g the `body`.

You can check which element was clicked inside the listener.

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr('class');
    $('#' + id).prop('checked', 'true');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a class="option-i-117">Option 117</a>
  <a class="option-i-118">Option 118</a>
  <a class="option-i-119">Option 119</a>
  <a class="option-i-120">Option 120</a>

  <input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-117" value="117">
  <input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-118" value="118">
  <input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-119" value="119">
  <input type="radio" name="option[236]" id="option-i-120" value="120">
</body>
```